# Mouse returns to home position when i drag

Tags: java, swing, mouse, label, drag

I have created a JLabel lab1. Added it to a panel and added mousemotionlistener to the label

```
 lab1.addMouseMotionListener(new InfoListener());
```

Here is the mouseDragged code

```
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){

            lab1=(JLabel)me.getSource();
            lab1.setLocation(me.getPoint());

    }
```

When i click and drag the label the position alternates between the moved point and home position of the panel and does not exactly move to where i want it to. The panel is in null layout and i have also mentioned setBounds for it initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
Point p=me.getPoint();

lab1.setLocation(p.x+lab1.getX(), p.y+lab1.getY());
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks. Can u tell me wat was the calculation mistake?

Comment: In the event you have coordinates of mouse on label (where your mouse was pressed). Suppose you press mouse in top left corner. So point is (1,1). But you need position on label container. So we add position of the label as well.

Answer (score 1):

1) code posted here talking nothing about your topic, edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating yout issue with `mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)`

2) please read tutorial about [Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1780__Drag-Drop.htm)

3) don't use [AbsoluteLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: +1 for the tutorials. I think null layout is fine in D&D when you position subcomponents whereever user drop them.

Comment: @StanislavL some of the very rare occasions where null Layout seems allowable - even then there are better options _with_ a manager: see Rob's DragLayout :-)